# Can an interrupt interrupt itself?

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I am using a pic16F690 with mplabv8.70, a pickit 2 and the hi-tech PICC PRO c compiler.

My question is whether this interrupt will be able to use the `getch` function within it as the `getch` function uses the RCIF flag which is also the flag used to trigger the EUSART interrupt.

Her is my code, sorry its long but people on here seem not to like putting snippets/sections rather than the whole thing. It multiplexs a 4 digit 7-segment LED display and gets a EUSART signal for the RPM value, however I want it to continue the display even when it doesn't receive the EUSART and then effectively 'update' when it does hence the interrupt and global variables. If there is an obvious better way then im happy to be told my way is wrong.

```
//#include _LEGACY_HEADERS              //Added for compiler versions 9.81+
#include <stdio.h>                      //For the printf function
#include <htc.h>                        //Compiler header file
//#include "usart.h"                        //USART header file
//#include "pause.h"
//#include "SerialIn.h"
//#include "Display.h"

__CONFIG(INTIO & WDTDIS & PWRTEN & MCLRDIS & UNPROTECT & UNPROTECT & BORDIS & IESODIS & FCMDIS);        //Configure the PIC with generic set up

#define BAUD 2400      
#define FOSC 4000000L
#define baudsetting ((int)(FOSC/(64UL * BAUD) -1))

#define RX_PIN TRISB5
#define TX_PIN TRISB7

#define dig0 0b01111110
#define dig1 0b00110000
#define dig2 0b01101101
#define dig3 0b01111001
#define dig4 0b00110011
#define dig5 0b01011011
#define dig6 0b01011111
#define dig7 0b01110000
#define dig8 0b01111111
#define dig9 0b01111011

unsigned char byte1;
unsigned char byte2;
unsigned char byte3;
unsigned char byte4;
unsigned char byte5;
unsigned char byte6;
unsigned char byte7;
unsigned char byte8;
unsigned char byte9;

unsigned RPMleft;
unsigned RPMright;

#define units 0b000001
#define tens 0b000010
#define hundreds 0b000100
#define thousands 0b001000

unsigned char RPM_unit;
unsigned char RPM_ten;
unsigned char RPM_hund;
unsigned char RPM_thou;

void interrupt isr(void);
void display_digit(unsigned char digit);
void multiplex(unsigned RPM);
void pause(unsigned usvalue);
unsigned char getch(void);
void init_comms(void);

void interrupt isr(void)
{   
    if (RCIF == 1)
    {
        byte2 = getch();                //Receive 8 bytes from the PICAXE
        byte3 = getch();
        byte4 = getch();
        byte5 = getch();
        byte6 = getch();
        byte7 = getch();
        byte8 = getch();
        byte9 = getch();

        byte2 = byte2 - 30;             //Convert the ASCII to equivilent integer
        byte3 = byte3 - 30;
        byte4 = byte4 - 30;
        byte5 = byte5 - 30;
        byte6 = byte6 - 30;
        byte7 = byte7 - 30;
        byte8 = byte8 - 30;
        byte9 = byte9 - 30;

////////Depending on which PIC is being used comment one of the following lines///////////////////////////////

        RPMleft = byte2*1000 + byte3*100 + byte4*10 + byte5;    //Save the RPM of the left prop shaft

//      RPMright = byte6*1000 + byte7*100 + byte8*10 + byte9;   //Save the RPM of the right prop shaft
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    /* General Setup */
    PORTA = 0;                          //Clear PortA
    PORTB = 0;                          //Clear PortB
    PORTC = 0;                          //Clear PortC
    TRISA = 0;                          //All PortA outputs
    TRISB = 0xFF;                       //All PortB inputs
    TRISC = 0;                          //All PortC outputs
    CM1CON0 = 0;                        //Comparators off
    CM2CON0 = 0;
    ANSEL = 0;                          //A/D module off

    INTCON = 0b11000000;                //Enable interrupts GIE = 1 (global interrupts), PEIE = 1 (periphaeral interrupts)
    PIE1 = 0b00100000;                  //Enable bit 5 RCIE = 1 (EUSART receive interrupt enable bit)

    init_comms();                       //Set up the USARTh

    while(1==1)                         //Loop Forever
    {
////////Depending on which PIC is being used comment one of the following lines////////////////////////////////////
        multiplex(RPMleft);
//      multiplex(RPMright);
    }//End while    
}//End main

unsigned char getch(void) {
    /* retrieve one byte */
    while(!RCIF)    /* set when register is not empty */
        continue;
    return RCREG;   
}

void init_comms(void)
{   
    RX_PIN = 1; 
    TX_PIN = 0;       
    SPBRG = baudsetting;        
    //Continuous 8 bit asynchronous non inverted low speed communication
    RCSTA = 0x90; // SPEN and CREN bit = 1, RX9EN = 0
    TXSTA = 0x20;//TXEN = 1, BRGH, SYNC = 0
    BAUDCTL = 0; //BRG16 = 0 
}

void multiplex(unsigned RPM)
{
    RPM_unit = RPM / 1000;                                  //Split the Left RPM value into 4 digits
    RPM_ten = (RPM / 100) % 10;
    RPM_hund = (RPM / 10) % 10;
    RPM_thou = RPM % 10;

    //Start Multiplexing

    PORTA = thousands;
    display_digit(RPM_thou);

    PORTA = hundreds;
    display_digit(RPM_hund);

    PORTA = tens;
    display_digit(RPM_ten);

    PORTA = units;
    display_digit(RPM_unit);
}

void display_digit(unsigned char digit)
{
    switch (digit)
    {
        case 0:
        PORTC = dig0;       //zero
        break;

        case 1:
        PORTC = dig1;       //one
        break;

        case 2:
        PORTC = dig2;       //two
        break;

        case 3:
        PORTC = dig3;       //three
        break;

        case 4:
        PORTC = dig4;       //four
        break;

        case 5:
        PORTC = dig5;       //five
        break;

        case 6:
        PORTC = dig6;       //six
        break;

        case 7:
        PORTC = dig7;       //seven
        break;

        case 8:
        PORTC = dig8;       //eight
        break;

        case 9:
        PORTC = dig9;       //nine
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: generally speaking, interrupts CAN interrupt themselves, but you have to be EXTREMELY careful to write re-entrant code so tthat the "child" interrupt doesn't stomp all over what the "parent" interrupt was doing.

Comment: "but people on here seem not to like putting snippets/sections" : this is not quite true, what people don't like is when essential parts of the code they are asking questions about is missing.

Comment: Your code looks suspicious to me, you call `getch` in the ISR where `getch` does a busy loop, so if no bytes can be retrieved, you never return from the ISR.

Comment: So, a mixture of interrupts, polling inside interrupt-handlers and no RTOS.  That's sure to work well:(

Comment: amongst other problems with the code; 1) the RCIF flag must be reset before exiting an interrupt, otherwise the interrupt will immediately be triggered again.   2) for the CPU, the time between successive bytes from a serial port is an 'eternity'.  so do not sit in a polling loop burning cpu cycles waiting for the next character to be available.  3) the code contains no way to determine if the currently read character is the first, the ...., the ninth.   4) in general, a interrupt handler should avoid making unnecessary function calls.

Comment: continuing. 5) the RCIF flag needs to be set to 0 in the initialization sequence.  6) the RCIF flag needs to be set to 0 just before returning from the interrupt handler

Comment: the interrupt handler should be only inputting one char.  not a string of characters.  the calculation of RpmLeft/RpmRight should be handled in Main().   However, there is the significant problem of how to determine when a input char is the first in each string of characters.

Comment: there is a variable: byte1 defined but not used.

Comment: to avoid race conditions, and similar problems.  The interrupt should not be enabled until after the associated peripheral is configured.

Comment: do not want to call 'multiplex()' until after a set of data is available to be displayed

Comment: the four variables rpm_unit, rpm_thou, etc are only needed in the multpilex() function, so they should be on the stack (auto variables) within the multplex() function.   I.E. never expose variables needlessly as that is an open invitation for another function to corrupt those variables

Comment: when writing a 'switch' statement, always include the 'default' case, even if the default case 'should' never be executed.

Comment: I would strongly suggest:  Rather than having two different executables, and having to be careful about which executable is loaded into which PIC.  Write the code to be able to handle either PIC, and having a input bit on the PIC that is tied either to ground or +vcc and the code read that bit to make the decision about which hardware that PIC is handling.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone especially @user3629249. Just to reply to a couple of your suggestions. 1) thanks had overlooked that 2) 3) I probably should have explained that I have programmed the CPU that sends data to the PIC and it will send it in 8 consecutive bits at baud2400 and I was hoping the gaps between this would be large enough for the first byte to be caught each time - if not i'll do a while loop to catch a certain character (byte1) in order to make sure the first is caught.5) didn't realise this assumed it would start at 0 on powerup. Thank you again for the comment

Answer (score 5):

In PIC16 architecture, an interrupt can't interrupt itself. Even if you clear the flag early the ISR will continue to run until it returns.

If you need nested interrupts switch to PIC18.

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep interrupt service routines as short as possible and avoid delays or code that takes too long to process in them. This way the program is ready to handle new Interrupts as fast as possible.

If an interrupt occurs while you are servicing another interrupt the microprocessor will re-enter the ISR again as soon as you exit it since the Interrupt flag is set.

In your code I think you can exit the ISR after reading the first character then continue execution until the next time the RCIF flag is set. Since you can execute quite a deal of code until another byte is sent trough USART.
If you create a buffer like byte[9] and a static pointer to remember which character you are receiving between ISR calls this should work.

Here is an example:

```
void interrupt isr(void)
{   
    static char pointer = 0;
    if (RCIF == 1)
    {
         byte[pointer]=getch();        // stores the incoming data in byte[0]-byte[8]
         pointer++;                  
         if(pointer==9)
         {
              pointer=0;               // Reset pointer
              // Other operations or flags that signal the expected data was received
         }
    }
}
```

Edit: I also think you need to clear the RCIF flag in software, check the datasheet to see if you need to do this manually or if the flag is cleared automatically if the buffer is empty.